# Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context of a protected function connecting to DB

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

My database connection file where I make the connection to the database and return it as an object.

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class db{   

    protected function connect(){
        try {
            $connect = new PDO("sqlsrv:server='.$servername.';database='.$bd.';",$username,$password);
            $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $connect;    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Error db(connect) '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The class where the query is executed

```
class Administrator extends db{
function view_count_users(){

    try {
        $SQL = 'SELECT  Count(*)
        FROM Users';
        $result = $this->connect()->prepare($SQL);
        $result->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error Administrator(view_users) '.$e->getMessage());
    } finally{
        $result = null;
    }

}

function get_view_count_users(){
        return $this->view_count_users();
}
```

The controller where I call the function from the parent that executes the query

```
<?php
class administratorController extends Administrator{
    function count_users(){
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card border-left-info shadow h-100 py-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                            <div class="col mr-2">
                                <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-info text-uppercase mb-1">Users
                                </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php echo parent::get_view_count_users(); ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="far fa-fw fa-calendar-alt  fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                    <?php
    }
    
}

?>
```

**Error:** Whenever I call the function view_count_users I get the error that I can't use $this when not in object context when the query is connecting to the db. Here: `$result = $this->connect()->prepare($SQL);`
This function is non-static so I can access since the controller is an extend of the db connecting file.

**THE complete Error:** `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\archer\models\Administrator.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\archer\controllers\administratorController.php(61): Administrator::view_count_users() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\archer\index.php(72): administratorController::count_users() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\archer\models\Administrator.php on line 57`

Comment: PLEASE, Always show us the complete error message, not your summary of it

Comment: So you're calling `parent::get_view_count_users()` __statically__. What do you expect then?

Comment: The error is right. You can only use `$this` when `new SomeClass()` has been called. Looks like you need to make all of your methods static and public then use self::connect or parent::connect in place of $this->connect()

Comment: when you extend a class you dont need to call the parent, change `echo parent::get_view_count_users();` to `echo $this->get_view_count_users();`

Comment: This way woudl also cause you to create a new connection for each query yo made in a script. That way lies madness

Comment: So what´s the best way to create a connection only one time and then use it in multiple queries